# Fastest parallel requests with variables in URL in python

Tags: python, api

I'm a bit stuck on the following.
Created a for loop that loops through a nested list of serial number and do the request.get. But this takes ages to complete.

**Nested list:**

```
[['MAC1', 'Serial1', 'Name1'],
 ['MAC2', 'Serial2', 'name2'],
 ['MAC3', 'Serial3', 'name3'],
 ['MAC4', 'Serial4', 'name4'],
 ['MAC5', 'Serial5', 'name5'],
 ['MAC6', 'Serial6', 'name6'],
 ['MAC7', 'Serial7', 'name7'],
 ['MAC8', 'Serial8', 'name8'],
 ['MAC9', 'Serial9', 'name9'],
 ['MAC10', 'Serial10', 'name10'], 
 ['MAC11', 'Serial11', 'name11'], 
 ['MAC12', 'Serial12', 'name12']]
```

**Function with For loop:**

```
def getrequest(devser):
    dict = {}
    try:  
        for lst in devser:
            r = request.get('https://api.test.com/%s' % (lst[1]))
            while r.status_code == 429:
                time.sleep(int(r.headers['Retry-After']))
                r = request.get('https://api.test.com/%s' % (lst[1]))
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    dict = r.json()
                    dlist.append(dict)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                dict = r.json()
                dlist.append(dict) 
        return(dlist)
    except:
        print('ERROR 01: Unable to contact')
        print ('API response: {}'.format(r.status_code))
```

Tried to use an async requests(Not sure if that is the best way). But it is looping the complete list instead of 5 per second.

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import requests

async def main():

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, requests.get, 'https://api.test.com/%s' % (lst[1])) for i in range(20)]
        for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
            print (response)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

What is the best way to handle these requests ?
and how can i implement it in the Function getrequest?

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for this issue.

Only need to workout the HTTP 429:

```
# Yield successive n-sized 
# chunks from l. 
def divide_chunks(l, n): 
    # looping till length l
    for i  in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
    # yield l[i:i + n] 
  
# How many elements each 
# list should have 
n = 5

lst = []
dlist = []
try:
    with FuturesSession(max_workers=10) as session:
        urls = list(divide_chunks(my_list, n))
        for items in urls:
            futures = [session.get(url[2]) for url in items]
        for future in futures:
            r = future.result()
            if r.status_code == 429:
                lst.append((r.url, divide_chunks(my_list, n )))
            elif r.status_code == 200:
                dict = r.json()
                dlist.append(dict)
        print (dlist)
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print (e)
```